# Netbeans not recognizing .tex file

Tags: java, netbeans, latex, typesetting

For an important project, I am trying to use the third-party library [JLR](http://www.nixo-soft.de/en/category/Downloads/page/libs/JavaLatexReport.php) to export a formatted PDF report.

This has been working correctly up until two days ago, when hovering over the .tex file I am using as a template for the report in the NetBeans IDE file viewer displays a tooltip denoting the file as an 'unrecognized file'. It will also no longer be imported as a resource, as when using the `getResource` method of the class or its `ClassLoader.getResource` method, the resulting `File` object does not exist. I have everything in the proper place in my working directory and am referencing it through a relative filepath.

1. What does this mean?
2. How can I get the file to be recognized?
3. Can I prevent this from happening again with this filetype?

EDIT: I have tried changing which MIME type NetBeans associates the file with to see if NetBeans recognizes it, but this has been unsuccessful.

EDIT: Here's the relevant code if anyone wants to see.

```
public Boolean createAndFormatLaTex(String nameOfExercise, String author, String date, String desc, List<Rule> rulesToPrint) {

    Boolean success = true;
    gen = new JLRGenerator();
    try {

        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

        URL templateLoc = cl.getResource("resources/templateRep.tex");
        File templateFile = new File(templateLoc.getFile());
        //URL workDirLoc = cl.getResource(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator);
        File workDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator);
        //URL tempDirLoc = cl.getResource(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator);
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator);
        File reptemp1 = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + nameOfExercise+"-report.tex");

        String s = templateFile.getAbsolutePath();

        templateFile.setReadable(true);

        conv = new JLRConverter(workDir);

        conv.replace("date", date);
        conv.replace("description", desc);
        conv.replace("authorName", author);
        conv.replace("nameOfExercise", nameOfExercise);
        conv.replace("rulesToPrint", rulesToPrint);


        if (!conv.parse(templateFile, reptemp1)) {
            success = false;
        }

        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop");
        if(!gen.generate(reptemp1, desktop ,workDir))
        {
            success = false;
        }
        reptemp1.deleteOnExit();
        tempDir.deleteOnExit();

    } catch (IOException iex) {
        System.out.println(iex.getMessage());
        return false;
    //} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
      //  Logger.getLogger(LaTexParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      //  return false;
    }catch(NullPointerException nex){
        Logger.getLogger(LaTexParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, nex);
        return false;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: uPLOAD YOUR CODE

Comment: @Adya The problem is not with the code, as it has functioned before, and I have not made any changes to it since it last functioned. I have reason to believe that it is the IDE or the JVM that is causing the problem. I have tried changing the MIME type to see if NeBeans recognizes it, but to no avail. Added the code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I aggregated solutions off of other people and the one that worked was to read the resource as an `InputStream` rather than as a `File`.

This would look as such:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

        InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("resources/templateRep.tex");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        //URL workDirLoc = cl.getResource(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator);
        File workDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator);
        //URL tempDirLoc = cl.getResource(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator);
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator);

        File reptemp1 = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + nameOfExercise+"-report.tex");
        File tempStorageFile = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "tempStorage.tex");

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempStorageFile);
        IOUtils.copyLarge(is, os);
        os.close();
```

replacing

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    URL templateLoc = cl.getResource("resources/templateRep.tex");
    File templateFile = new File(templateLoc.getFile());
    //URL workDirLoc = cl.getResource(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator);
    File workDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator);
    //URL tempDirLoc = cl.getResource(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator);
    File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"MaMoOr"+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator);
    File reptemp1 = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + nameOfExercise+"-report.tex");

    String s = templateFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

in my original code.